# Reading an xml file from a jar file

Tags: java, xml, encoding, embedded-resource

I am trying to read an XML file from a jar file.  Here is the file I am tying to read:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
<foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/layered_app_icon" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

Here is my code:

```
// ...            
final JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(is, true);
JarEntry je;
try {
    while ((je = jis.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
        final String filename = je.getName().toLowerCase();
        // ...
        String str = "-->" + new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(jis));
```

The output:

```
��4
adaptive-iconandroid                                                                                                       drawable

background

foreground**http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android�


        �����$��������8������������
                                                                                    ����������������������������������������4
    adaptive-iconandroid                                                                                                       drawable

    background

    foreground**http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android�
                                                          �����$��������8������������
                                                                                    ��������������������������������������
```

I tried other charsets like UTF_16 and ISO_8859_1 but nothing worked.

Comment: Why can't you use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream`?

Comment: My class is parsing a 3rd party jar file.  Can I use Class#getResource or Class#getResourceAsStream in that situation?

Comment: If it’s available in the classpath

Comment: This jar file is not available in classpath as it's not part of the application.